# Minimizing $(q_1, q_2, \dots, q_K) \mapsto \left(\sum_{i=1}^K\frac{p_i^2\sigma_i^2}{q_i}\right)\left( \sum_{i=1}^Kq_i\tau_i\right)$ with a constraint

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, monte-carlo

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset {q_1, q_2, \dots, q_K} {\text{minimize}} & \displaystyle \left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^K \frac{p_i^2\sigma_i^2}{q_i} \right) \left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^K q_i\tau_i\right) \\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle \sum\limits_{i=1}^K q_i = 1 \end{array} $$

It turns out that, the optimal $q_i$ is

$$ q_i^* = \dfrac{\frac{p_i\sigma_i}{\sqrt{\tau_i}}}{\sum\limits_{\ell = 1}^K \dfrac{p_{\ell}\sigma_{\ell}}{\sqrt{\tau_{\ell}}}}.$$

The first method that comes to mind is by using Lagrangian method. I have
$$
\mathcal{L}(q,\lambda) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^K\frac{p_i^2\sigma_i^2}{q_i}\right)\left( \sum_{i=1}^Kq_i\tau_i\right) + \lambda\left(\sum_{i=1}^Kq_i - 1 \right).
$$
Then,
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q_j} = \left(-\frac{p_i^2\sigma_i^2}{q_i^2} \right)\left( \sum_{i=1}^Kq_i\tau_i\right) + \tau_j\left(\sum_{i=1}^K\frac{p_i^2\sigma_i^2}{q_i}\right) + \lambda.
$$
So, $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q_j} = 0$ implies
$$
q_j = \frac{p_j\sigma_j\sqrt{\sum_{\ell = 1}^Kq_{\ell}\tau_{\ell}}}{\sqrt{\tau_j\sum_{\ell = 1}^K\frac{p_{\ell}^2q_{\ell}^2}{q_{\ell}} + \lambda}}.
$$
Usually, to find $\lambda$ I would just solve
$$
\sum_{j=1}^K \frac{p_j\sigma_j\sqrt{\sum_{\ell = 1}^Kq_{\ell}\tau_{\ell}}}{\sqrt{\tau_j\sum_{\ell = 1}^K\frac{p_{\ell}^2q_{\ell}^2}{q_{\ell}} + \lambda}} = 1
$$
for $\lambda$. But the equation looks very difficult to solve. Is there a trick that I can use to solve this?

---

**Motivation**

This question comes from a theoretic study of Monte Carlo simulation for reducing variance. One technique to reduce variance is called [stratified sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling). The idea is to create partition of the population you want to sample from. But, how do we choose the allocation? This optimization problem is to find the optimal allocation.

Comment: The Lagrangian method can be quite complicated when dealing with general inequalities with $N$ variables. Try using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Suppose you minimize the expression for some $q$ not necessarily subject to the condition. Then letting $A=\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^K q_i}$ (perhaps $\sum_{i=1}^K q_i\neq 0$ is the only condition), you can see that $q' = Aq$ achieves the same value while satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^K q_i' = 1$. This is another reason why the Lagrangian is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Rn_-_n-dimensional_Euclidean_space):

$$\left( \sum_{i=1}^K\frac{p_i^2\sigma_i^2}{q_i} \right) \left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^K q_i\tau_i\right)  \ge \left(\sum_{i=1}^K \frac{p_i\sigma_i}{\sqrt{q_i}}\cdot 
 \sqrt{q_i\tau_i}\right)^2 =\left(\sum_{i=1}^K p_i\sigma_i 
 \sqrt{\tau_i}\right)^2$$

The equality occurs if and only if

$$ \frac{p_1\sigma_1}{\sqrt{q_1}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{q_1\tau_1}} =\dots=\frac{p_K\sigma_K}{\sqrt{q_K}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{q_K\tau_K}} $$
$$\iff \frac{q_1}{p_1\sigma_1\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau_1}}}=\dots=\frac{q_K}{p_K\sigma_K\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau_K}}} \tag{1} $$

With the condition $\sum_{i=1}^K q_i = 1$, from $(1)$, we can deduce that the equality occurs if and only if
$$ (1) \iff \frac{q_1}{p_1\sigma_1\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau_1}}}=\dots=\frac{q_K}{p_K\sigma_K\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau_K}}}  = \frac{\sum_{l=1}^K q_l}{\sum_{l=1}^K p_l\sigma_l\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau_l}}} = \frac{1}{\sum_{l=1}^Kp_l\sigma_l\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau_l}}}$$
$$\iff \frac{q_i}{p_i\sigma_i\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau_i}}}= \frac{1}{\sum_{l=1}^Kp_l\sigma_l\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau_l}}}\hspace{1cm} \forall i=1,\dots,K$$

or

$$q_i =\frac{p_i\sigma_i\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau_i}}}{\sum_{l=1}^Kp_l\sigma_l\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tau_l}}}  \hspace{1cm} \forall i=1,\dots,K$$

Comment: Your solution presumes that $\tau_i\geq 0$ and $q_i\geq 0$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,K\}$

Comment: @Norbert The author forgot the condition that $q_i \ge 0$ (if not, the minimum should be $-\infty$. Indeed, suppose $\tau_1 \ge \tau_2 \ge 0$, just take $q_1 \to -\infty$, $q_2 = 1-q_1$ and  all other $q_i = 0$). He wrote $\sqrt{ \tau_i} $ so $\tau_i $ must be all positive.

Comment: @NN2 I agree with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but how do you get the condition to get the equality. Also, $\sum_i \frac{s_i}{t_i} \neq \frac{\sum_i s_i}{\sum_i t_i}$ right?

Comment: @Vicky I added more detail for how to get the $q_i$. Besides, I **did not** use $$\sum_i \frac{s_i}{t_i} = \frac{\sum_i s_i}{\sum_i t_i}$$
I used instead
$$\frac{s_1}{t_1} = \frac{s_2}{t_2} =..=\frac{s_K}{t_K}  \color{red}{= \frac{\sum_i s_i}{\sum_i t_i}}$$